# How to grant owner permissions on a path to a new user on Puppet?

Tags: puppet

There is a folder on the machine that currently own by *Administrators* group and I want to add a new owner without removing the existing one. Here is the code that I came up with.

```
file { 'my_destination':
    path => extlookup('my_destination'),
    ensure => directory,
    recurse => true,
    source => extlookup('my_source'),
    owner => 'XXX',
    group => 'TEST_XXX',
    mode => 0777,
    require => File['my_root_destination'],
}
```

Unfortunately, this code removes existing users and groups and sets owners to *XXX* and *TEST_XXX* which is not what I want.

How to grant permissions to new groups or new users on Puppet without removing the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet currently cannot manage complex ACLs on [windows file resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/writing.html#filefile).  All it does it translate Unix style permissions to windows and ensures those don't change (which is why your modifications on the permissions are removed).

To accomplish what you're looking to do, you'll have to remove the owner, group, mode parameters from the file resource and create an exec resource to set the ACLs via [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx).